# "expo-module-scripts" not working on Windows. How to npm install successfully?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently in the process of downloading a React Native project, including iOS, Android, and web. However, at this stage, I only intend to focus on the Android and web development aspects since I only have a PC. When attempting to execute "npm install" to set up the project, an error is encountered.

```
node_modules\expo-module-scripts\bin\expo-module-build:3
set -eo pipefail
        ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
npm ERR! code 1
```

As far as I know the "expo-module-scripts" is not working for windows.If so, how can I run the environment successfully and skip the ios part? Thank you

Run the environment and able to develop Android and web for the project

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: Yes, first of all, create a Linux environment. Run bash in your virtual machine,then do "npm install" in your Linux bash. Then you can go back to your windows and run your project.